# Promise outside of for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a for loop like so:

```
var currentLargest
for (var site in sites) {
    // Each site is a website (www.mysite1.com, www.mysite2.com, etc.)
    $.getJSON(site).then(function(data) {
       if (data > currentLargest) {
           currentLargest = data
       }
    });
}
// Here is where I want to use "currentLargest"
```

It checks multiple different websites to get the largest value. However, I can't extract the data I need **after** the for loop. I can only interact with `currentLargest` from within the promise, but that data is only relevant for ONE of the sites (it hasn't finished looping through all them until after the for loop).

How can I access the `currentLargest` value after the for loop containing the `getJSON` promises?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Basically that's not possible in the way you're imagining. Since the `getJSON` call is async, there is no way to access the `currentLargest` synchronously after the loop. You have to access that data via a `.then` function, like any other result that's based on an async operation.

Comment: @CRice How could I structure this, then?

Comment: You'll want to put all the `getJSON` promises into an array, then use `Promise.all` to await the completion of all of them, then calculate the largest and do what you need with it in the `.then` of that `Promise.all`.

Comment: @CRice I'm trying this implementation, but having trouble figuring out how to transcribe my `sites` array into `Promise.all()`. If you have time, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Your code:
/*
var currentLargest
for (var site in sites) {
    // Each site is a website (www.mysite1.com, www.mysite2.com, etc.)
    $.getJSON(site).then(function(data) {
       if (data > currentLargest) {
           currentLargest = data
       }
    });
}
*/

// Updated:
const sitePromisesArr = sites.map((site) => $.getJSON(site));

$.when(sitePromisesArr)
  .then((valArr, index) => {
    // The "valArr" here will be an Array with the responses
    const largest = valArr.reduce((current, next) => next > current ? next : current, 0);
    
    // This will be the largest value.
    console.log(largest);
    
    // This will be the site that contains the largest value.
    console.log(sitePromisesArr[index]);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great, and I'll accept it! Is there a way I can keep track of what site the largest value came from, though?

Comment: Yes. I will update my answer to provide you that information.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning => I have updated my answer to give you that information as well.

Comment: After testing, this doesn't work. Variables are still undefined when I do a `for` loop that loops through `valArray`. How can I make the promise have fully resolved by then?

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning => Can you please provide an example of the `sites` array? Maybe there is something wrong with that.

Comment: `const sitePromisesArr = sites.map((site) => $.getJSON("site.com/api/specificuser?=" + site));`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a async loop and then execute a callback once all the async getJSON requests are finished. You could use http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each to help with this.